# Left Join tables on column sum to column value

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, cursor, while-loop, left-join, common-table-expression

I have two tables; SamplesTbl that contains samples every 5 seconds of a bike ride, and a RxTbl that contains the prescribed stages and other values of a bike ride:

SamplesTbl ( SamplesID int SessionNum int StageNum int RunTime int )

RxTbl ( RxID int RxNum int RxStageNum int RxRunTime int )

In certain cases (not all) a prescribed bike ride is broken up into more stages than prescribed (5 stages are turned into 20 stages). Currently I use cursors and temporary table to take these 20 stages to map them back to the 5 prescribed stages based on the number of stages it takes from the samples table to equal the prescribed run time.

For example, stage 1 is prescribed at 5 minutes but the actual exercise data would contain stages 1 through 5 that equal the 5 minutes (1-4: 65 seconds, 5: 40 seconds), stage 2 is prescribed at 3 minutes but the actual exercise data would contain stages 6 through 8 that equal the 3 minutes (1-2: 65 seconds, 3: 50 seconds), etc.

Is there a way to retrieve the result set without using cursors and/or temp tables?